# sim card sizes. Why start with the big one

Tags: cellphone, sim

Sim cards come in various sizes standard(1ff), mini(2ff), micro(3ff) and nano(4ff).

Many questions I see tend to say there are many advantages to using the smaller size such as placement within the phone itself allowing for easier layout of components. So why did we start with sim cards the size of credit cards then slowly move down is size instead of simply starting at nano which has no waste material and can be positioned as easily as possible.

Was this addition plastic used simply as a shielded way to hold the card with old electronics or is there another reason I'm missing.

Comment: Why did we start with mobile phones with 7 segment displays the size of bricks? Why did we start with computers the size of buildings? Why did turing build the bomba instead of writing a javascript for his smartphone?

Comment: well that would be down to how well we can build these things the key part of a sim card is always the same size with varying amount of plastic around it

Comment: besides that this is not true for the old ones, where the chip itself is bigger than todays nano sizes, you also need all the small and flimsy mechanical parts that hold it. Since the 90s also these things have improved in terms of bang per buck.

Answer (score 4):

The miniaturization of electronics is a process and takes time to refine a design, as well as manufacturing processes that physically create the electronic device, down to their most efficient state.

At the time of its inception, the SIM card used an internal chip that was a specific size.  As the design of the chip was refined, the SIM card no longer needed to be so large, hence the miniaturization of your overall SIM card.

This is the inherent progression of designing chip electronics

Comment: That's really interesting. I always thought they just started off unnecessarily large, but it makes sense they needed all the space they could get at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Larger cards are less likely to be lost by customers and are easier to make mechanical supports for. Also I would expect that the chips in early cards may well have been bigger than the ones in current cards.